# Javascript Table Not Showing

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple javascript html table so I can put dynamic data in to it but it wont show when I check my browser. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can get it to show on the page the way I have it? Thank you!

```
    <head>
    <title>Test JS Table</title>
    <script Language="JavaScript">

        var nrCols=2;
        var nrRows=4;
        var root=document.getElementById('mydiv');
        var tab=document.createElement('table');

        tab.className="mytable";

        var tbo=document.createElement('tbody');
        var row, cell;

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    .mytable {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:200px;
    }

   .mytable td{
    border:1px solid #000000;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script language="javascript">
        tab.className="mytable";

        for(var i=0;i<nrRows;i++){
          row=document.createElement('tr');

         for(var j=0;j<nrCols;j++){
               cell=document.createElement('td');
               cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("ROW DATA HERE..."))
               row.appendChild(cell);
         }

         tbo.appendChild(row);
        }

      tab.appendChild(tbo);
     root.appendChild(tab);

    </script>
    <div id="mydiv"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your JavaScript is executing before the HTML has been processed, so the `<div>` doesn't yet exist and can't be found using `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist how do I get it so it will work the way I have it could you help me?

Comment: @FrankG. [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/edAbv/)... I moved your javascript inside the header to the javascript in the body and moved the `<div>` so it's over the javascript so the script has access to it

Comment: @ClydeFrog that was it... Thank you very much. I guess it didn't work because I was calling the div after the script was already done?

Comment: @FrankG. No, your first script in the header tried to create a table (`<tbody>`) inside a element called `mydiv` which didn't exist yet. and then your other script inside the body tried to write rows inside a element called `mytable` which wasn't created because of the earlier circumstances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the script in to `window.onload`. When you execute the script the div does not show yet, so it cannot get id for you

Or put the script below the div

```
<head>
<title>Test JS Table</title>


<style type="text/css">
.mytable {
border-collapse:collapse;
width:200px;
}

.mytable td{
border:1px solid #000000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div id="mydiv"></div>

<script Language="JavaScript">

    var nrCols=2;
    var nrRows=4;
    var root=document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var tab=document.createElement('table');

    tab.className="mytable";

    var tbo=document.createElement('tbody');
    var row, cell;

</script>

<script language="javascript">
    tab.className="mytable";

    for(var i=0;i<nrRows;i++){
      row=document.createElement('tr');

     for(var j=0;j<nrCols;j++){
           cell=document.createElement('td');
           cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("ROW DATA HERE..."))
           row.appendChild(cell);
     }

     tbo.appendChild(row);
    }

  tab.appendChild(tbo);
 root.appendChild(tab);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No reason those script blocks couldn't be combined into a single block too.

Comment: @nnnnnn with all due respect I am new to javascript. Sorry I'm not a pro like you. Everyone likes to bash others with there Egos instead of bashing me show me how to do it. That's why I am here to learn. But your to good to do that. Thanks but no thanks for your help!!!!!!

Comment: @FrankG. - What bashing? I simply advised that you can combine the two script blocks. I'm genuinely confused how you could find that offensive.

Comment: @nnnnnn It's not that I find it offensive more so not helpful. Its easy for everyone to say hey do this... And that's real frustrating when you don't know how to. If I knew how to I would heck, I wish I knew how to code the whole thing I wouldn't need stack. I take it back it's my fault for not asking how to combine them. So I apologize for not asking. Thank you for your help!! Sorry!

Comment: @FrankG. - OK. How to combine the blocks? If you've got two script blocks right next to each other you'd remove the closing `</script>` from the first and opening `<script>` of the second such that what is left is one big block with all of the JS code from both. In the case of script blocks that aren't right next to each other it might not make sense to combine them, but if you did you'd move all of the code from the second block to the end of the first, then delete the second block - or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a common a error for beginners. An HTML file is read from top to bottom, the html analysed and the javascript executed as it is encountered. Your Javascript tries to find the div with id mydiv before the html with the corresponding div is found.

A simple way around this is to place your script at the bottom, before the closing body tag.

```
<head>
    <title>Test JS Table</title>


    <style type="text/css">
    .mytable {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:200px;
    }

   .mytable td{
    border:1px solid #000000;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="mydiv"></div>

     <script Language="JavaScript">

        var nrCols=2;
        var nrRows=4;
        var root=document.getElementById('mydiv');
        var tab=document.createElement('table');

        tab.className="mytable";

        var tbo=document.createElement('tbody');
        var row, cell;

        tab.className="mytable";

        for(var i=0;i<nrRows;i++){
          row=document.createElement('tr');

         for(var j=0;j<nrCols;j++){
               cell=document.createElement('td');
               cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode("ROW DATA HERE..."))
               row.appendChild(cell);
         }

         tbo.appendChild(row);
        }

      tab.appendChild(tbo);
     root.appendChild(tab);

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[Here's a live example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edAbv/)